# Why do I get these syntax error messages?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm in CS50 and heres my greedy.c

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
    int cents[1000];
    int used[1000];
    used = 0;
    printf("How much change is due? (Don't use symbols ex: 0.45)\n");
    scanf("%d", cents);
    if (cents < 0) {
        printf("Please use positve numbers only \n");
        scanf("%d", cents);
    };
    while (cents >= 0.25) {
        cents -= 0.25;
        used+1;
    };
    while (cents >= 0.10) {
    cents -= 0.10;
    used+1;
    };
    while (cents >= 0.05) {
    cents -= 0.05;
    used+1;
    };
    while (cents >= 0.01) {
    cents -= 0.01;
    used+1;
    };
    printf("%d", used);
}
```

Can someone explain why it doesnt work? I keep getting this error message :

```
greedy.c:8:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[1000]’ from type ‘int’
  used = 0;
       ^
greedy.c:15:15: error: invalid operands to binary >= (have ‘int *’ and ‘double’)
  while (cents >= 0.25) {
               ^
greedy.c:16:9: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int[1000]’ and ‘double’)
   cents -= 0.25;
         ^
greedy.c:19:15: error: invalid operands to binary >= (have ‘int *’ and ‘double’)
  while (cents >= 0.10) {
               ^
greedy.c:20:9: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int[1000]’ and ‘double’)
   cents -= 0.10;
         ^
greedy.c:23:15: error: invalid operands to binary >= (have ‘int *’ and ‘double’)
  while (cents >= 0.05) {
               ^
greedy.c:24:9: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int[1000]’ and ‘double’)
   cents -= 0.05;
         ^
greedy.c:27:15: error: invalid operands to binary >= (have ‘int *’ and ‘double’)
  while (cents >= 0.01) {
               ^
greedy.c:28:9: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int[1000]’ and ‘double’)
   cents -= 0.01;
         ^
greedy.c:31:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d", used);
  ^
make: *** [greedy] Error 1
```

EDIT: Okay so thanks to @Digital_Reality I got it to compile but now if I passthrough 1.25 I get we used 1 coin and if I pass through 1000.00 its says we used 1000 coins does anyone know a fix?

Comment: You defined `cents` and `used` as arrays but treat them as single values.  Which one is it?

Comment: You don't really need `cents` and `used` to be 1000-element arrays, do you? If you're under the impression that `int cents[1000];` declares `cents` as an integer with a maximum value of 1000, re-read your textbook.

Comment: Okay so I got rid of the 1000 and it still doesn't work @KeithThompson

Comment: @mrnatbus12: You "got rid of the 1000"; does that mean you have `int cents[];`? It "still doesn't work"; what on Earth does that mean? What does your program look like, and what error message(s) are you getting now? (And a minor point: I'm guessing CS50 is a computer science class, but do you expect everyone to know that?)

Comment: @KeithThompson it looks like int cents;

Answer (score 1):

Three problems I see!

1--> You have defined `cents` as array of `1000` elements are using as single integer

2--> your scanf is incorrect! (& missing)

```
 scanf("%d", &cents);
```

3--> your `cents` is `int` `array` and you are trying to use if for `float / double.`

**Edit:**

Read some basics here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Comment: Okay I got rid of the 100 and added the symbol but now the last line doesnt work error :                                                          greedy.c:31:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
      printf("We used %d coins", &used);                                                         ## EDIT ## : I fixed it nevermind

Comment: in printfs you should not use &.

Comment: yeah I just changed it @digital_Realilty

Comment: Okay I did compile but not necessarily work check the edit please

Answer (score 0):

make both the declared cents and used as just double variable not an array

```
      double cents;
      double used;
```

scanf has to passed an address so make it &variable

```
     scanf("%lf",&cents);
```